# Programming Timer0 on PIC16F882 for a value greater than maximum PRESCALER

Tags: timer, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm using the [PIC16F88X](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41291D.pdf) which has a 200ns internal clock period and I want to program the `TIMER0` to make 4 measurements per second.

According to [microchip tutorial on programming timer 0](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51682A.pdf) (page 10) I can use `PS0`, `PS1` and `PS2` to assign `TMR0 RATE` to 1:256 but this only makes my clock period scale to 51,2 micro seconds.

There is also the possibility to program an initial value for `TMR0` but I don't think it will affect the clock I want to reach. Is there anything on the big picture that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

It is expected that timer prescaler can't cover any range that user may want. In order to achieve larger intervals you have to add additional logic in yours timer interrupt routine. Basically you have to add additional variable/counter which you have to increment, let's say on 50us (you will tune timer from 51,2us to 50us by adding initial value to `TMR0`). When your counter reaches 5000 then you have wanted 1/4s resolution.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I forgot to specify that `TMR0` is a 8-bit counter, so it only goes up to 256. So is the maximum period it can count before overflowing 256 * 51,2us ?

Comment: Exactly. 

As stated in [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41291D.pdf)

The Timer0 module is an 8-bit timer/counter with the
following features:
• 8-bit timer/counter register (TMR0)
• 8-bit prescaler

Which means that your calculation is correct, that you have to choose values for ```TMR0``` and prescaler then to implement your own code in ISR.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specification sheet (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41291D.pdf) page 76 we see that the timer1 available on this micro-controller is 16bit and has up to 8 pre-scaler. My own approach would be to use timer1 with a prescaller of 8. Without seeding the value manually, this gives :

```
<osc speed>/(4*<prescaller>*2^16)
5MHz/(4*8*2^16) = 2.38Hz
```

To get exactly 4Hz, you can seed the counter on every rollover to a value of :

```
2^16-<osc speed>/(<desired speed>*4*<prescaller>)
2^16-5MHz/(4Hz*4*8) = 26474
```